# TexShop2016 Showing Error in Console

Tags: texshop

I am a new user to Latex. I haven't been able to run any file in Texshop. The following thing pops up in the console every time I try to run something[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUHD0.png)

This is how my preferences tab looks like [image]

If somebody could please point out the problem here!
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are typesetting with pdftex rather than pdflatex. Use Shft–Cmd-L to typeset with pdflatex or place the line `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex` at the top of your source file and typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T).

Comment: Also it looks like you wrote `\document` instead of `\documentclass` on the first line.